# Date is different when working on microsoft edge but correct when working on Chrome or Firefox

Tags: angular, browser, .net-core

I am facing a weird issue. I am working on an application where frontend is in angular 7
and web API is in Dotnet core.

From the frontend, I am sending a string that contains JSON data. I parse it into and object in the backend.

It is working fine in Chrome and other browsers but not with the edge so to find out the root cause i did debug and found that it is throwing an exception while parsing the string to object and specifically  while parsing the date so.
 I compared the string and string looked exactly same . Below are the string

**From other browsers**
{"WidgetID":3,"ProviderIDs":"2,3","MonthIDs":"","StartDate":"1/1/2019","EndDate":"12/31/2019","Class1Ids":"","Class2Ids":"","Class3Ids":"","Class4Ids":"","EmployeeStatusIds":""}

**From edge**
{"WidgetID":3,"ProviderIDs":"2,3","MonthIDs":"","StartDate":"‎1‎/‎1‎/‎2019","EndDate":"‎12‎/‎31‎/‎2019","Class1Ids":"","Class2Ids":"","Class3Ids":"","Class4Ids":"","EmployeeStatusIds":""}

but the string from edge was throwing exception while parsing the date part.

So I thought I should compare the strings in some online comparison tool there I found the issue
Please find in below image.
[image]

Please look at the red dots in date below changed text label.

Please find below the code in the angular which is parsing the json into string in angular

```
getDashboardData(filterCriteria: any): Observable<any> {
        let param = "jsonCriteria=" + JSON.stringify(filterCriteria);
        return this.apiService.get('AnalyticalDashboard', 'GetBenefitProviderCosts', param)
            .map(res => {
                return res;
            });
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me on how I can fix this issue in the angular.

Thanx

Comment: I think the server should return the dates in a different format (e.g. ISO 8601). By default, ASP.NET Core should do this right though (you can customize this, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539394/6996150), so I am guessing your dates in the backend are currently in string format?!